# How to make the text block size as big as the text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with my menu which has 100% width on screen and its height is 90px,I have 2 text inside the menu,and the problem is that the text blocks size are much bigger than the text,they are as high as the menu container height
I'll show you in picture to understand better.

[image]

So as you can see the light blue is the block of the text,the orange is the margin,and the red is the size what I want to make from the light blue block.

And for some reason the `float:right` doesn't work either,I tried on the Help text,but nothing happened.

So can someone help me in that also to look like this:

[image]

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

.container {
    display:inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.container h2 {
    font-size: 38px;
    margin-top: px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 90px;
    margin: 0 30px;
     
}
.container a {
    display: contents;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    transition: .3s;
}
.container a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a{
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    transition: .3s;
}
a:hover{
    color: #0092f3;             /*#1056c9;*/
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-login.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a81368914c.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <!--  <img src="logo.svg" class="logo" width="250px" height="77px"> -->
    <a href="index"><h2>Home</h2></a>
    <div class="help">
    <a href="help"><h2>Help</h2></a>
      </div>
    
    </div>  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some changes to make to your CSS. The commented out fields are the ones that I removed from your post:

```
.container {
  align-items: center;
}
.container a {
  /* display: contents; */
}
.container h2 {
  /* line-height: 80px; */
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

.container {
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.container h2 {
    font-size: 38px;
    margin-top: px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 30px;
    display: inline;
     
}
.container a {
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    transition: .3s;
}
.container a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a{
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    transition: .3s;
}
a:hover{
    color: #0092f3;             /*#1056c9;*/
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-login.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a81368914c.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <!--  <img src="logo.svg" class="logo" width="250px" height="77px"> -->
    <a href="index"><h2>Home</h2></a>
    <div class="help">
    <a href="help"><h2>Help</h2></a>
      </div>
    
    </div>  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: But its not working well,the size of the text block are still as high as the container,and if I move my mouse under the text I can still click on the link.

Comment: Updated to remove the `line-height` property, which was causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you! And do you know why the `float:right` isn't working?
When I try to position the Help text to the right side of the screen

Comment: Since your `.container` is a flexbox, try using `.container { justify-content: space-between }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by reducing line-height property inside container h2 {}.